# Writing JSON Object as Object not as String to File

Tags: java, json, gson, objectmapper

I want to write a JSON Object to a file.Currently I have tried using ObjectMapper and Gson but they are writing the JSON as JSONString, Thus the output file has JSON string rather than object. So is there a way JSON Object is written as Object rather than String

```
JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject(response.getBody().toString());
org.json.simple.JSONObject object  = new
org.json.simple.JSONObject(responseData.toMap());
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objMapper.writeValue(new File(path) , object);
```

Now the above code is writing the JSON Object as String in to file not a JSONObject.

Comment: Can you please explain in little details. What you actually want and what will be output.

Comment: I want is that when JSON is written to file, then it should not appear as a String in one line. Rather it should be JSON Object format.

Comment: Go through this link you will get that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379171/write-to-jsonobject-to-jsonfile

Comment: any reason for not preferring String to file and wanted to store in JSONObject?

Comment: You can explore BSON format: https://json-bson-converter.appspot.com/

Comment: Add simple examples of what you now get and what you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ObjectMapper. You can achieve this with org.json.simple.* package itself.

```
    package com.tutorial

    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    public class JosnObjectWrite {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject(response.getBody().toString());
            JSONObject object  = new JSONObject(responseData.toMap());

            try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/<username>/Documents/file1.txt")) {
                file.write(object.toJSONString());
                System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
                System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + object);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. But here also object is written as String and would appear in one line in file. I need it to appear as JSONObject .